# Next.js external script not loading properly, second client component won't display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Next.js 14.0.3

I am developing a small and simple web app with Next.js, but I am seeing some very strange bugs. The app uses a node package to display charts from data that comes from a database. It sets a javascript interval to refresh its data. I'll explain the problems I'm having below.

Here are my 3 source files. (To save space, I removed the SQL queries. They are well-tested and are not causing these problems.)

page.tsx

```
import Chart from './Chart.tsx';

const ServerComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Chart divID="xau-usd-candlestick" refreshMinutes="5" chartType="candlestick" currencyFrom="xau" currencyTo="usd" decimalPlaces="2" />
            <Chart divID="cny-usd-candlestick" refreshMinutes="5" chartType="candlestick" currencyFrom="cny" currencyTo="usd" decimalPlaces="4" />
            <Chart divID="try-usd-candlestick" refreshMinutes="5" chartType="candlestick" currencyFrom="try" currencyTo="usd" decimalPlaces="6" />
            <Chart divID="irr-usd-candlestick" refreshMinutes="5" chartType="candlestick" currencyFrom="irr" currencyTo="usd" decimalPlaces="8" />
            <Chart divID="btc-usd-candlestick" refreshMinutes="5" chartType="candlestick" currencyFrom="btc" currencyTo="usd" decimalPlaces="2" />
        </div>
    );
};

export default ServerComponent;
```

Chart.tsx

```
'use client'

import styles from './page.module.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Script from 'next/script'

async function renderChart (divID, chartType, currencyFrom, currencyTo, decimalPlaces)
{
    let url = 'http://localhost:3000/api?chart-type=' + chartType;
    url += '&cur-from=' + currencyFrom + '&cur-to=' + currencyTo + '&decimal-places=' + decimalPlaces;

    await fetch (url)
        .then ((response) => { return response.text (); })
        .then ((data) => { Highcharts.stockChart (divID, JSON.parse (data).data); })
        .catch ((error) => { console.log (error, currencyFrom); });
}

function Chart (props)
{
    if (typeof props.refreshMinutes != 'undefined' && props.refreshMinutes > 0)
    {
        useEffect (() => {
            const interval = setInterval (renderChart, props.refreshMinutes * 60000, props.divID, props.chartType, props.currencyFrom, props.currencyTo, props.decimalPlaces);
            return () => { clearInterval (interval); };
        }, []);
    }

    let css = `${styles.chart}`;

    return (
        <div className={styles.main}>
            <div id={props.divID} className={css}>
            </div>
            <Script
                src = "https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"
                onReady = { () => { renderChart (props.divID, props.chartType, props.currencyFrom, props.currencyTo, props.decimalPlaces); }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Chart;
```

api/route.ts

```
const { Client } = require ('pg');

const pg_client =
{
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432,
  database: 'db_name',
  user: 'xxxxx',
  password: 'xxxxx'
};

const db_client = new Client (pg_client);
async function connect () {
    await db_client.connect ();
}
await connect ();

async function getCandlestickData (cur_from, cur_to, decimal_places)
{
    return new Promise (async (resolve, reject) =>
    {
        var query = 'select .....';
        await db_client.query (query)
            .then ((db_result) =>
            {
                for (let i = 0; i < db_result.rows.length; i++)
                {
                    db_result.rows [i].x = Number (db_result.rows [i].x) * 1000;
                    db_result.rows [i].open = Number (Number (db_result.rows [i].open).toFixed (decimal_places));
                    db_result.rows [i].close = Number (Number (db_result.rows [i].close).toFixed (decimal_places));
                    db_result.rows [i].low = Number (Number (db_result.rows [i].low).toFixed (decimal_places));
                    db_result.rows [i].high = Number (Number (db_result.rows [i].high).toFixed (decimal_places));
                }

                let result =
                {
                    plotOptions: {
                        candlestick: {
                            color: 'pink',
                            lineColor: 'red',
                            upColor: 'lightgreen',
                            upLineColor: 'green'
                        }
                    },
                    rangeSelector: { selected: 1 },
                    title: { text: cur_from + '-' + cur_to },
                    series: [
                                {
                                    type: 'candlestick',
                                    name: cur_from + '-' + cur_to,
                                    data: db_result.rows
                                }
                            ]
                };

                resolve (result);
            })
            .catch ((error) => { reject (error); });
    });
}


export async function GET (request: Request) {

    let data;
    let url = new URL (request.url);
    let chartType = url.searchParams.get ('chart-type');

    if (chartType == 'candlestick')
    {
        let currencyFrom = url.searchParams.get ('cur-from').toUpperCase ();
        let currencyTo = url.searchParams.get ('cur-to').toUpperCase ();
        let decimalPlaces = url.searchParams.get ('decimal-places').toUpperCase ();
        await getCandlestickData (currencyFrom, currencyTo, decimalPlaces).then ((result) => { data = result; });
    }
    return Response.json({ data });
}
```

There are several problems I'm seeing, but here are the main two:

The weirdest thing I am noticing is that the second chart in the list does not display. If I rearrange the `<Chart>` elements in `page.tsx`, it is still the second one that doesn't display. It seems like the `onReady` function for the `<Script>` element never gets called but I have no idea why. It works fine for the other elements, but never for the second one.

At random times, I get the error `Highcharts is not defined`. So the code is trying to use the Highcharts object before it is fully loaded? I thought the `onReady` event was supposed to prevent that. Is there something wrong with the way I am using the `<Script>` tag? Is there a better way to load an external script than the way I am doing it?

Comment: every time that component rerenders its going to load that script again. I don't think its a good idea to be dynamically adding script tags in components. Maybe load it in the html component so its only loaded once, or copy the javascript into your project and export the chart library yourself and import as a dependency in your component/